Is there a way to write a file directly to external storage in Expo?
I'm developing an app similar to KeePassXC that encrypts and decrypts data from/to files. Reading a file is straightforward with expo-document-picker, but when I try to save new data to the file I just read (using expo-file-system), I get the following error:
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
    filePath, // file path of the file it was read before
    encrypt(password, data, iterationsInt) // function which encrypts data text
);

Failed to save file: [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.writeAsStringAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Documents/testDir/database.2fa]

From what I've read in the Document Picker documentation, I understand that I can't directly access external storage due to the app's sandboxing. The documentation mentions that to work around this, I should use the copyToCacheDirectory option to make the file accessible immediately after it is picked.

When using expo-document-picker with expo-file-system, it's not always possible for the file system to read the file immediately after the expo-document-picker picks it.
To allow the expo-file-system to read the file immediately after it is picked, you'll need to ensure that the copyToCacheDirectory option is set to true.

But saving data to cached file is not overwriting the original one.
Currently, I’ve worked around this by allowing the file to be saved to external storage using expo-sharing, but the user must overwrite the file every time new data is added, which is inconvenient.
const tempFilePath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName;

await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
    tempFilePath,
    await encrypt(password, data, iterationsInt)
);

await shareAsync(tempFilePath, {
    dialogTitle: "Save File",
};

Question:
Do I need to eject from Expo to access external storage, or is there a way to allow my Expo app to write directly to the original file path after using the expo-document-picker?
